# Software to sort non-photo image files from photos (if photo files lack from EXIF/metadata)

Tags: windows, android, linux, images, photography

Trying to sort out my photos, which have all kinds of file types and not necessarily any useful camera metadata (like date taken or camera type, etc) that would help me to work out what was a photo without looking at every single thumbnail. Is there any software which can sort through thousands of images and work out what's a photo and what's not?

Windows 7, Linux, or Android... I'm looking for free software, but would consider something very cheap (<5 USD).

Comment: This thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354744/how-to-detect-if-an-image-is-a-photo-clip-art-or-a-line-drawing/9407786#9407786 might be helpful in figuring out what type of image classification needs to be done to figure out if a file is a photo or not. There is some serious image processing that needs to be done if there is no metadata available to properly classify an image as a photo. Couple tools that might be helpful here namely Google Vision API https://cloud.google.com/vision/ which is cloud based or Ghiro http://www.getghiro.org/ which is open source.

Comment: Just trying to have a look at Ghiro, not really sure how to run it? No executable. Looks like I have to compile it. Will report back

Comment: If you make this comment into an answer, I'll award you the bounty regardless, since yours is the only response that suggested something other than exif.

Comment: Thanks @NeMo. I made my comment an answer. Ghiro offers a virtual appliance (VMware and VirtualBox) that you can run as well so you might not need to compile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354744) might be helpful in figuring out what type of image classification needs to be done to figure out if a file is a photo or not. There is some serious image processing that needs to be done if there is no metadata available to properly classify an image as a photo.

Couple tools that might be helpful here namely [Google Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision) which is cloud based or [Ghiro](http://getghiro.org) which is open source.

Answer (score 1):

We had to find all illustrations, cliparts, etc. and separate them from our image collection.
Searching for *EXIF* data could work but only if we had all images with meta data. So we needed to find another way which analyses the contents of the images.

What really worked for us: cliparts and illustrations have high contrast and usually high brightness so using the search engine of [ImageRanger](http://imageranger.com) we were 
able to find the majority of the files and move them to a new folder.

Comment: That sounds very promising. I'll give it a go when I get a chance

Answer (score 0):

You should try

**Zoner Photo Studio**  - https://www.zoner.com/en/spectacular-free-photo-editor.

It has robust photo shorting functions (ex. by exif data). I think there is a trial period and just for $8 per month.

Comment: or this one is for free http://www.amok.am/en/freeware/amok_exif_sorter/

Comment: Could you please create another answer about EXIF Sorter? By the way, does it detect photo/non-photo for files that do not contain EXIF/etc metadata?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) Software to search for all the images in your entire PC or in a particular folder. The software will index each and every file in your computer, even hidden files upon startup. You can give the particular folder path in which you want to identify the images of all types and it will scan within milliseconds.

The software is very lightweight, around 500KB only. It is free to use.

From the menu, you can click Search -> Pictures and it will show you all the images. Then you can proceed with the deletion or whatever you want.

Comment: I already know how to show all the image files, I want something to only show me the *photos*.

Comment: So, do you want to sort images based on the EXIF data, like organizing them into a folder based on date or something?

I think this would be helpful : https://askubuntu.com/questions/404567/how-to-organize-sort-images-by-exif-image-data

Comment: For now I just want to establish what's a photo and what isn't.

Comment: It does not detect photo/non-photo. If it does, please provide a webpage about this feature or screenshot showing it in action, thanks!